# DataField<T> and DataField<T?>

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Is there a way which works? Of course the following code doesn't work: :-)

There are multiple types of DataFields: `int, string, DateTime, double, MyOwnType`

The DataFields themselves are wrapped into a generic class and the type of them is of type T. All the T's, which are value types, are nullable, though (`int?, DateTime?, double?`). That's for storing reasons for our database.
If a value is null we don't create a new record for that data field in our database.

```
public void SetDataFieldValue<T>(string fieldName, T value)
{
    DataField<T>.Value = (T)(object)value;
}
```

That works perfectly fine with the nullable T's. But if we call it like

`SetDataFieldValue<int>("NumberOfChildren", value)`

it won't work, because `DataField<int>` does not exist. So I need something like this (we just need that for empty inputs):

```
public void SetDataFieldValue<T>(string fieldName, T value)
{
    var defaultValue = default(T);
    if (defaultValue.GetType().IsValueType)
    {
        // This T? just works with value types.
        // Of I set a constraint where T: struct this would work.
        // So the if statement above is not enough to tell the compiler,
        // that in here only value types of T are handled
        DataField<T?>.Value = // whatever 
    }        
    if (defaultValue.GetType().IsReferenceType)
    {
        DataField<T>.Value = // whatever 
    }
}
```

So if you call it with `int?` you determine that you don't want to store the value if it's null. If you call it with `int` instead it's gonna be stored with `0` (a record is created).

Please don't suggest things like changing the design of our DataFields. One reason for not creating a new DB record, if the value is null, is, that null has been defined as "no information" (**null** children of a family is not a intentionally set field). "0" is information though (**0** children).

### **UPDATE**

Sorry. I forgot to mention that we have a `public T GetDataFieldValue<T>(string fieldName)`, as well. And there we can't determine just the type of the value.

The definition of our data fields says, if our data field is nullable, the value of it should be nullable as well. That should work for not nullable (actually not existing) data fields, as well.

**So if we say `GetDataField<int>` we want to return `(int)DataField<int?>.Value`.**

But we can't cast it with `(int)` if the value is `null`. So we do it like this:

(T is `int`)

```
if (DataField<int?>.Value == null)
{
    return default(T);
}
return (int)DataField<int?>.Value
```

The only way I see at the moment is that we call this method like `GetFieldValue<int?, int>(name)` if we want to get back a not nullable integer. Else we call `GetFieldValue<int?, int?>` for getting back a nullable integer.

Obviously there is no way to create overloads with constraints? So the first method has `where T: struct` and the overload `where T: class`?

Comment: `defaultValue.GetType()` will fail if T is a reference type, because `defaultValue` will be null... why don't you use `typeof(T)` instead?

Comment: That's exactly what we want. Sorry, that I forgot to tell you about that.

Comment: `we don't create a new record for that data field`.  That doing it wrong.  Very wrong.

Comment: @Hans Passant: could you please explain that again in other words? I don't understand your sentence (foreigner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just call it with `Nullable<Int>`?

`SetDataFieldValue<Nullable<int>>("NumberOfChildren", value)`

EDIT:

`GetDataFieldValue<T>(string fieldName)` can also be called with Nullable.  To get the value of T, use `typeof(T)`:

```
public T GetFieldValue<T>(string fieldName) {
    var theTypeOfT = typeof(T);
}
// Call this using Nullable<T>:

var someNullableInt = GetFieldValue<Nullable<T>>("foo");
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that we have a `GetDataFieldValue<T>(string fieldName)` as well. And there we can't determine the type of the value. We just determine it through the type of the data field and the return value gets casted with that type. And there it's also wished to handle not nullable value types. The casting with (T) is not the problem. The problem just is, that `GetDataField<int>("ChildrenCount")` tries to get the `Value`of `DataField<int>`. And that doesn't exist.

Comment: @ebeeb: so what do you want GetDataField<int>("ChildrenCount") to return then?

Comment: **@zespri**: That should return an `int` **@Chris Shain**: If you get a field value with `GetFieldValue<Nullable<T>>` you return `DataField<Nullable<T>>.Value`. So if you get a value with `GetFieldValue<int>` you try to return `DataFieldValue<int>.Value`. But as I told, `DataField<int>` does not actually exist.

Comment: Have a look at my **UPDATE** again, please. I reexplained the problem better, now.

Comment: Int is a value type.  It cannot be null, so you'd need to return a sentinel value in the case when the underlying database field is null.  If you call the function with Int? as the type argument, you can coalesce the resulting value: `var iN = GetFieldValue<Nullable<T>>("foo"); var i = iN.HasValue ? iN.Value : 0;`

Comment: @ebeeb I think the point is that you should never call `GetFieldValue<int>`; instead, you should call `GetFieldValue<int?>` (a.k.a. `GetFieldValue<Nullable<int>>`).